# Express $(1+\cos(x-1))^3$ as a trigonometric polynomial in x.

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, boundary-value-problem

Express $(1+\cos(x-1))^3$ as a trigonometric polynomial in x. I keep doing this problem and somehow I keep messing up the constants, and it just jumbles up in my head.

$$(1+\cos(x-1))^3$$ 
$$= (1+\cos(x-1))(1+\cos(x-1))(1+\cos(x-1))$$
$$= (1+\cos(x-1))(1+2\cos(x-1)+\cos^2(x-1))$$ 
$$= 1+3\cos(x-1)+3\cos^2(x-1)+\cos^3(x-1)$$

Now I hope I've got this correct so far, but after this I making some kind of mistake.

$$=1+3(\cos1\cos x+\sin1\sin x) + 3/2+3/2\cos2(x-1) +3/4(\cos1\cos x+\sin1\sin x) +1/4\cos3(x-1)$$

But then how do I do $\cos2(x-1)$ and $\cos3(x-1)$ ?

Comment: You have the coefficients right - the binomial formula applies here as well.

Comment: in $x$... would this indicate only $\cos(mx)$ and $\sin(mx)$ type terms? If so then you need to expand via the adding angles formula for cosine; $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$. For example, $\cos(x-1)=\cos(1)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\sin(1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expand the "inside" of the parenthesis *first* into $1+\cos(1)\cos(x)+\sin(1)\sin(x)$. Now think of this as $A+B+C$ and expand $(A+B+C)^3$ via usual algebra, for example there will be a term $6ABC$ (and several others). After that if you put the suggested things back for $A,B,C$ it will be a polynomial in $\cos(x),\sin(x).$